pip ubuntu deliver such output "Requirement %s: %s (%s)"
I use ubuntu 22.04, with python3.10.
i dont know why, suddently from pip and vllm all output  look like this :
tarik@tata-linux1:~/AI-WS/CodeGeeX4$ pip install vllm
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/, https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/pypi/simple
Requirement %s: %s (%s)
Requirement %s: %s (%s)
Requirement %s: %s (%s)

by vllm also:
tarik@tata-linux1:~/AI-WS/CodeGeeX4$ python -m vllm.entrypoints.openai.api_server --model THUDM/codegeex4-all-9b --trust_remote_code --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080 --uvicorn-log-level debug --api-key xxxx --max_model_len 65000 --dtype float16 --device cpu
INFO 07-24 05:04:24 api_server.py:54] vLLM API server version %5.3f.
INFO 07-24 05:04:24 api_server.py:216] vLLM API server version %s
INFO 07-24 05:04:24 api_server.py:217] args: %s
WARNING 07-24 05:04:27 config.py:1378] Casting %s to %s.

my environment:
Linux tata-linux1 6.5.0-44-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jun 18 14:36:16 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Python 3.10.12 (main, Mar 22 2024, 16:50:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
does anybody know how to solve this problem?
I reset the terminal and also reboot but it change nothing
I reset the terminal and also reboot but it change nothing
i reinstalled pip also no improvement. i think it is not a pip or vllm problem
in python if i do
print('The value of pi is approximately %5.3f.' % math.pi)

, it work well
vllm use  logger  all logger.info
AAAA=3.14
logger.info("vLLM API server version %5.3f.", AAAA)
INFO 07-24 05:04:24 api_server.py:54] vLLM API server version %5.3f

are wrong : . pip the same
